# how do i set up a www. CNAME with a heroku ssl which is not a wildcard

Tags: cname-record, heroku

I have a website foo.com which uses heroku expedited SSL which has a SSL certificate registered to `https://foo.com`.

I would like a request to `www.foo.com/any/path` to render `https://foo.com/any/path` without a redirect. Is there any way i can do that without a wild card SSL certificate? I tried registering a `CNAME` for www which points to `https://foo.com`. I thought that would then render my main ALIAS record of `https://foo.com` to the expedited-heroku-url but it didn't. maybe i set it up wrong?

EDIT: 
Actually currently when you go to `www.foo.com/any/path` it redirects to `https://foo.com` but drops the path. having the behavior `www.foo.com/any/path` redirect or be a CNAME for `https://foo.com/any/path` would be acceptable. But the current simple redirect of any path the plain old `https://foo.com` is not the behavior I am seeking.

Answer (score 0):

From Godaddy you can only permanent redirect to heroku because ssl certificate installed on heroku only. IF you want to use your dns and server from heroku then you need to enable your billing first then you can go though below attched link. Temperary redirection in that case will not work because it will through error that connection is not private because certificates are installed for heroku only. After enable billing heroku will install your dns certificates and then you can use heroku + ssl. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170664/how-to-configure-heroku-application-dns-to-godaddy-domain

Comment: Add a CNAME record and put your app url and host without http or https and that's it.